# AJAX POST & PHP POST In Same Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 dropdowns called `drpcategory` and `drpitem` as below;

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Category</label>
<select class="form-control bg-dark btn-dark text-white" id="drpcategory" name="drpcategory" required>
<?php
$category = ''.$dir.'/template/post/category.txt';
$category = file($category, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($category as $category)
{
echo "<option value='".$category."'>$category</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div> 

<div class="form-group">
<label>Item</label>
<select class="form-control bg-dark btn-dark text-white" id="drpitem" name="drpitem">
<?php
$category = $_POST["drpcategory"] ?? 'Electronics';
$item = ''.$dir.'/template/post/'.$category.'/item.txt';
$item = file($item, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($item as $item)
{
echo "<option value='".$item."'>$item</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
```

As you can see, depending on the selected value of `drpcategory`, the `drpitem` should be dynamically populated.

In case you were wondering, both dropdowns will go through the PHP loop and populate if I set `$category` manually without any `post` checks.

Now, I'm using AJAX `post` to post the changes in `drpcategory` into the same page as below;

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    $('#drpcategory').on('change',function()
    {

      $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
          alert(data);
        }
      });

    });    

  });
</script>
```

Here is the **Chrome** Browser > **Inspect** > **Network** tab output for the above AJAX `post`;

[image: Inspect]

And yes, I'm `post`ing this AJAX into the same page and the `url` is: `http://example.com/?page=post` which is the same as this Network tab shows.

I have removed the `url` field from AJAX function because the browser automatically picks up the current page so it's better, and no, manually writing any `url` in there didn't change anything about what I'm about to ask below.

Question is, how can I make that `drpitem` to pickup the AJAX `post`ed `drpcategory` value and start populating dynamically?

I want to AJAX `post` to the same page and all of this should happen without a page reload.

Comment: well first of all,  you fundamentally started it wrong; Dont place php inside dome elements if you are working with ajax; you put all php on top and fetch post request; and return object that you can use to populate forms with js ; this will never work, you'll be returning all html elements

Comment: @Milan Rilex Ristic Exactly. I get a return of all html elements. Better if someone can order this code and post a working model because I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172523/1117368

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST jQuery variables to PHP in same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172312/how-to-post-jquery-variables-to-php-in-same-page)

Comment: @mujuonly No, that didn't solve my issue. His file has nothing within `<body>` tags, but in my file the above 2 dropdowns are within `<body>` tags. Also he is calling files in AJAX  `url` and getting  `json` data. It appear as the same question but too hard for me to understand until someone post a working model answer for my exact question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after waiting more than 7 days trying to figure this out, I couldn't AJAX `post` to the same page probably because there are too much of `<html>` elements already in the same page. But here goes it using an external `post.php` file. Only these changes were required for me to get this working other than mentioned in my original question above.

```
<script>
$(function()
{
$('#drpcategory').change(function()
{
$.ajax({
method: 'post',
url: 'post.php',
data: $(this).serialize(),
success: function(data)
{
$('#drpitem').html(data);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

Then I had to save this `post.php` in the root website directory where `index.php` is located. Change your directory as necessary and also remember to change the `url` field in the above AJAX function.

```
<?php include 'config.php';?> //this is where the $dir variable is derived in my website. i had to include this since post.php is an external file that doesn't know about the variable.

<?php
$category = $_POST["drpcategory"];
$item = ''.$dir.'/template/post/'.$category.'/item.txt';
$item = file($item, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($item as $item)
{
echo "<option value='".$item."'>$item</option>";
}
?>
```

Thank you for each and everyone of you for walking me through this. I would have marked someone of you as the answer if a direct answer was given but if someone already given this, I'm sorry for not understanding you properly. But I think the end goal is for someone to use this as help.

Comment: "I couldn't AJAX post to the same page probably because there are too much of <html> elements already in the same page".  That's why my first answer demonstrated the PRG pattern:  first work your post and then either redirect or die before any other output.  It'll work in your index.php page if you really want it there; you just have to do all your PHP stuff before there's any HTML stuff.  Anyway, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You get return of all html elements?
Please make 'if condition' in your php function if Post request occur return php result else return html elements.
Whats is the '/?page=post' in your url ? please var_dump($_POST,$_GET); in ajax request function please give me the response.
Otherwise can you please send this request to newly created function for test propose?

Comment: It's hard for me to understand this whole process. If you can just copy paste my code in the question into a file and post a working model here, it would be easy for me to understand since I have tried everything. Just change `$dir` variable to a folder you like and test it yourself, but I think you already know what it is.

Comment: <script>
 $(function(){

    $('#drpcategory').on('change',function()
    {

      $.ajax({
        url :"new_php_request_page.php",
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
          alert(data);
        }
      });

    });    

  });
</script>

new_php_request_page.php

<?php 

var_dump($POST,$_GET);
?>

Comment: <script>
 $(function(){

    $('#drpcategory').on('change',function()
    {

      $.ajax({
        url :"request_in_same_page_url.php",
        method: 'post',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
          alert(data);
        }
      });

    });    

  });
</script>

Comment: request_in_same_page_url.php                        ->                    

<?php 

if(isset($POST)) { //ajax request return; }                                                                   else { //code here ,return html elements ,when no post request occure                   
      }                         ?> 
?>

Comment: Can I do this in the same file without that external `request_in_same_page_url.php` file? You can just copy paste the code in my question and try for a direct answer because right now that's will be the only way I can catch this.